# How can I properly set a variable through a PowerShell script and then consume it in another using Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have a first inline PowerShell script where I am filtering my test project directory and setting its value to a variable called `testProjectPath`.

```bsh
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Get tests path"
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      $testpath = Get-ChildItem -Filter *Tests.csproj -Recurse | Select-Object Directory -First 1
      
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testProjectPath]$testpath"
```

And then I have a second script which tries to `Set-Location` based on the path present in my `testProjectPath` variable.

```bsh
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Run mutations"
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      Set-Location $env:testProjectPath
```

But every time I try to run this pipeline I get the following error message:

```
@{Directory=D:\a\1\s\Wms.PickingCheck.Tests}
Set-Location : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Directory=D' does not exist.
At D:\a\_temp\752e8e31-b8ac-4f43-9ee0-248f6b12577c.ps1:4 char:1
+ Set-Location $env:testProjectPath
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (@{Directory=D:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @AdminOfThings I don't need the full path (which includes file name), I just need the path where the test file is located.

Comment: You need to use property `DirectoryName` and the `-Expand` parameter (to yield just the value) -> `$testpath = Get-ChildItem -Filter *Tests.csproj -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand DirectoryName -First 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original script, the value of `$testpath` is `@{Directory=xxxxxx}`. However, `Set-Location` doesn't recognize this format, `Set-Location` sets the current working location to a specified location, that's why you got error:

[image]

You could modify your script by adding `-Expand` as @AdminOfThings mentioned: `$testpath = Get-ChildItem -Filter *Tests.csproj -Recurse | Select-Object -Expand DirectoryName -First 1`

[image]